# elaticsearch finding multiple exact values - how to escape colon in the value

Tags: elasticsearch, escaping

For the single value match,

```
{
  "match" : {
    "price" : 20
  }
}
```

if the search value is with :, such as "address:1 smith street", I can escape the :

```
{
  "match" : {
    "address" : "address\\:1 smith street"
  }
}
```

The above query will work.

But when I try to find multiple exact values, instead of "match" I would need to use "terms"

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

```
{
  "terms" : {
    "price" : [20, 30]
  }
}
```

then when the search value with : in them, escape : will not work

the following queries both are not working

```
{
  "terms" : {
    "residence" : ["address:1 Smith Street", "address:2 David Road"]
  }
}

{
  "terms" : {
    "residence" : ["address\\:1 Smith Street", "address\\:2 David Road"]
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You could also use a `bool/should` with multiple `match` queries.

Comment: Thanks Val.

It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Val, bool/should with multiple match queries will work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should" : [
            {"match" : {"residence": "address\\:1 smith road"}},
            {"match" : {"residence": "address\\:2 david street"}}]

          }
      }
   }
}
```